# Testing whether $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are sampled from standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

What are the possibilities to test whether R.V. come form normal distribution i.i.d.:

$$X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(0,1)$$

What we need to measure and what is the MVUE statistic to test
$H_0$ that they are vs. $H_1$ that they are not ?

What is the size and power of this test ?

Comment: this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test

Comment: @Golden_Ratio This is good, but a full paper on the topic would be better ?

Comment: Are you testing for normality, generally? Or specifically, for **standard** normal? How large is $n?$

Comment: @BruceET Standard would be enough for me to begin with. $n$ is suitable one.

Comment: Did you check out the Razali, Nornadiah; Wah, Yap Bee (2011) paper mentioned in wiki?

Comment: @user122424 If you want to test specifically standard normal, this seems like an easier test, no? For instance, we can reject the null if the sample average is far enough from zero.

Answer (score 3):

This more of a rebuttal than an answer. I hope to
convince you that you need to state the purposes of
your project, take sample size into account, and
say what alternatives to standard normal are important
to you. Whatever test(s) you consider, you will need
additional context.

One major difficulty with tests of normality
is that they may have very poor power (ability to detect
departure from normal) for small samples, and that they
may reject for a large sample that is very nearly normal, but
not in ways that matter for practical purposes.

Another is that the alternative can make a large difference
in the behavior of a test of normality. And that you do not state an alternative. Is your alternative
that the data are not normal even though the population from
which the test sample were randomly sampled has mean other
than $\mu = 0, \sigma=1?$ Or is the alternative that the population is not normal?

Consider several scenarios using the **Kolmogorov-Smirnov test**
of $H_0$ that data are sampled from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

**Small samples:** $n = 10.$ In none of the cases is the
null hypothesis that data are standard normal rejected.
This is the appropriate result only for the first test,
in which data *are* standard normal. Following @GolderRatio's suggestion a t test is included in the one instance in which
$\mu \ne 0.$ [R code. For brevity, `$`-notation is used to show
only P-values for most of the tests.]

```
set.seed(1022)
n = 10
x = rnorm(n)             # standard normal data
ks.test(x, pnorm, 0, 1)  # appropriately fails to reject

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.11601, p-value = 0.9966
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

y = rnorm(n, .25, 1)      # Normal, but mean 0.25
ks.test(y, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val
[1] 0.1230996             # Falsely fails to reject
t.test(y)$p.val                     
[1] 0.2673517             # t test fails to rej wrong mean 
t = rt(n, 50)             # pop not exactly normal
ks.test(y, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val
[1] 0.1230996             # slight non-normality not detected
u = runif(n, -sqrt(3), sqrt(3))  # uniform population     
ks.test(u, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val   
[1] 0.1454823             # fail to detect non-normality 
w = rexp(n) - 1           # shifted exponential data
ks.test(w, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val
[1] 0.4284639             # fail to detect non-normality
```

**Large samples:** $n = 1000$ For large samples all but the first test with standard normal data are strongly rejected
with P-values very nearly $0$---even
for the 'essentially' normal t data with DF=50.

```
set.seed(1022)
n = 1000
x = rnorm(n)
ks.test(x, pnorm, 0, 1)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.029514, p-value = 0.3484
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

y = rnorm(n, .25, 1)
ks.test(y, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val
[1] 5.050318e-08
t.test(y)$p.val
[1] 9.776068e-11
t = rt(n, 50)
ks.test(y, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val
[1] 5.050318e-08
u = runif(n, -sqrt(3), sqrt(3))
ks.test(u, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val
[1] 0.000140186
w = rexp(n) - 1
ks.test(w, pnorm, 0, 1)$p.val
[1] 0
```

Comment: Your answer is quite nice but I'd need Matlab's code. Is that possible for you to include it in your answer ?

Comment: BTW, what language is your code from ?

Comment: Don't have access to Matlab. And I don't suppose Matlab has a full array of statistical tests. Sorry I didn't say my code is from R